# How is this copper showpiece making static electricity

Tags: static, static-electricity, electrostatic

I'm trying to make a showpiece which generate static electricity just like in this YouTube video [LINK](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g2rdsBoomBU)

Does it have Tesla Coil (Slayer Exciter) inside it or Negative Ion Generator?

Comment: Or the guy holding the bill is rubbing himself with a woven scarf...

Comment: 10 rupees must be a series RC capacitor with arc resonant air gap about 1~ 10mA with 5kVdc arcing at some current limited frequency. The arc temperature is over 5000’C but not at the surface so it doesn’t burn easily but starts.  Any fluorescent ballast will work shockingly well.

Answer (score 0):

It's not static electricity, static fields dissipate rapidly after dischraging.

Most likely a tesla coil, or a high voltage AC source connected to the object.

A negative Ion Generator would dissipate it's field rapidly

Comment: a basic tesla coil with 2n2222a and 22K resistor would do the job.?

Comment: I can't measure the current on the video so I have no idea, I will leave that up to your experimentation

Comment: is that can be achieved using USB ionic air purifier.?